# How to redirect urls to dynamic subdomain using htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, urlparse

First of all.I would like to ask that how to make subdomain redirection using htaccess. 
    www.samcheck.com/www/google.com to google.com.samcheck.com

I have tried all the solution available on the stackoverflow.But none of the solutions worked for me.

As well as the URL is `https://sampcheck.com/www/google.com` , I want it to be `https://google.com.sampcheck.com` so that it shows the content of main url.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . index.php [L]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.sampcheck.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.([^.]+)\.sampcheck\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sampcheck.com/www/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I actually doubt that you tried "all the solution available on stackoverflow"... But even if that were the case, then what do you expect from us? If really all answers ever given here to redirection questions "do not work" for you (without you telling us why not), then how should we answer to this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "none worked for me"? What does that actually mean? What appened? What do you see in your http servers error log file?

Comment: There are several issues with the code you posted. One is: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.sampcheck.com` does not make any sense. It would only match something like "xsampcheckycomfoo" for example. That is not what you want, I assume. Also it contradicts the second condition following right behind...

Comment: Also the final host name you code in that second rewriting rule contradicts what you ask in your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comments to the question and my puzzlement what sense such host naming scheme should make (except for cheap phishing attempts), here is something that should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.samcheck\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?www/([^/]+)/?$ https://www.$1.sampcheck.com/ [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

Also note that such redirection can only work if you actually have valid certificates for those dynamic host names...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: thank you for the help :) I have edited the question and added more details. I am literally a noob and new in this.Please help me!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://sampcheck.com/www/google.com --> https://google.com.sampcheck.com

Comment: I want this result^. If you can give me the rewrite rule for this, then i shall be very grateful to you.

Comment: look into this.

Comment: But that is exactly what the rule in this answer does...(except for the "www." prefix which you can simply remove).

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.samcheck\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?www/([^/]+)/?$ https://$1.sampcheck.com/ [R=301]

correct?

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Have fun! And give back here on SO in future, thanks!

Comment: Sure! hey @arkascha can you look into this problem too.I have similar problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782949/how-to-set-credentials-in-new-amazon-alexa-com-rank-api-in-php

Comment: Hey @arkascha can you look into this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880793/how-to-get-value-of-input-form-using-jquery-while-i-am-geting-null