# How to set credentials in new Amazon Alexa.com Rank API in Php?

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on new Alexa.com Api and testing it out and I having a problem setting credentials in it. I have an access key and secret key but not Session Token and Expiration.Idk where to get them.
Also see this

```
$awsCredentials = $result->get('Credentials');
```

and I could not find its root to set credentials.

I have an access key and secret key for my Alexa API calls. And I have setup up AWS SDK for PHP 3

```
protected function SetCredentials($awsCredentials) {
      $this->accessKeyId = $awsCredentials["AccessKeyId"];
      $this->secretAccessKey = $awsCredentials["SecretKey"];
      $this->sessionToken = $awsCredentials["SessionToken"];
      $this->expiration = $awsCredentials["Expiration"];
    }
```

How do I set credentials?

Here is the urlinfo.php code:

https://github.com/aws-samples/alexa-web-information-service-api-samples/blob/master/php/urlinfo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your php version or your account is not verified.